# Does $f(x+f(y))=f(x)+f(y)$ imply $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-f(0)$, given $f(0)\neq0$?

Tags: functional-equations

We are given a function $f\colon R\to R$ that satisfies $f(x+f(y))=f(x)+f(y)$ for any real $x,y$, and also $f(0)\neq0$. The equation seems to be entirely dependent on the values of $f$. It seems impossible to have anything to say about $f(x+y)$ just from manipulations with the equation; which suggests a more inventive approach should be of use. Clearly, functions of the form $x+b$ (with $b\neq 0$) satisfy mentioned properties. So, it suggests the function in the question has some properties of the latter. That is, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-b$ or $f(pf(0))=pf(0)+f(0)$ for a rational $p$.

Here is what I have found:

- $f(x)=f(x-f(0))+f(0)$,
- $f(x+nf(y))=f(x)+nf(y)$, $n\in Z$ (in particular, $f(nf(x))=f(0)+nf(x)$),
- $f(-f(0))=0$.
- Surjectivity would imply $f(pf(0))=pf(0)+f(0)$ for any $p$.

But... that's all. No continuity, no injectivity, not even anything like $f(px)=pf(x)$, like for the Cauchy's functional equation. And it seems plausible that there are pathological solutions with their graphs dense in $R^2$. Anything beyond these facts seems to be walking in circles without any meaningful conclusion. Does anyone have clues?

---

The original problem is from [mock IMO 2023](https://web.evanchen.cc/static/mop/mockimo/2023.pdf):

> Find all rational numbers $q$ for which there exists a function $f\colon R\to R$ satisfying $f(x+f(y))=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(z)\neq qz$ for all real numbers $x, y, z$.

Intuitively, I guessed that the only rational number that answers the question is $q=1$. And it is easy to infer $f(0)\neq 0$. From these conclusions I started to work things out. The matter in my question would help to prove that $q=1$ is indeed the only number to have such a function.

---

Edit note. The user from AoPS [constructs](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1562368p9557553) solutions for this functional equation using additive subgroups of $R$, but with $f(0)=0$, and it can be seen that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-f(0)$ doesn't hold. It remains to verify it against $f(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: What's the source of the problem, if I may? This could help locate an existing solution if it's an older contest question for example.

Comment: This [AoPS post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2004807p14028639) might help. (Found with [Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%5Cleft(x%2Bf%5Cleft(y%5Cright)%5Cright)%3Df%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%2Bf%5Cleft(y%5Cright)%24&p=1))

Comment: @BrunoB, it's from [mock IMO 2023](https://web.evanchen.cc/static/mop/mockimo/2023.pdf)

Comment: The original question asks something different. and the liked AoPS post seems to have the answer

Comment: @DS, yes, I've just guessed intuitively that $q=1$ is the only rational number to answer it. And if $f$ satisfies the conditions in the original question, $f(0)\neq0$, so that's where I started to work things out.

Comment: A small observation: $f(x+C)=f(x)+C$ given $C\in im(f)$. And thus $f(C)=f(0)+C$. So if it is surjective then it is linear of the form $x\mapsto f(0)+x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it *doesn't hold*. Following the construction given at AoPS, we can put
\begin{align}f(x)=c+\lfloor\sin(2\pi x)\rfloor+\lfloor x\rfloor\end{align}

for an integer constant $c\neq 0$. Numerically, using GeoGebra and some values, I was able to see that this function should satisfy the functional equation. And to prove it, notice that $f(y)$ is an integer

\begin{align}
f(x+f(y))&=c+\lfloor\sin(2\pi x+2\pi f(y))\rfloor+\lfloor x+f(y)\rfloor\\
&=c+\lfloor\sin(2\pi x)\rfloor + \lfloor x\rfloor +f(y)\\
&=f(x)+f(y)
\end{align}

But, it doesn't satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-f(0)$.

Take, for example, $c=5$, $x=-14.6$, $y=-27.8$, then we have
\begin{align}
f(x+y)=-39\neq -38=f(x)+f(y)-f(0)
\end{align}

Comment: This doesn't resolve the original question though, does it?

Comment: @DS, yet it answers _my_ question which is in the title.

Comment: @DS, and it follows (it shows) that we instead need some sophisticated approaches, rather than obtaining some properties similar to linear functions $x+b$ and then obtaining the result for the original question from it.

Comment: @DS, if you eventually happen to find a solution to the original question, I invite you to write an answer ;)

Comment: While doing some thinking, I found that all negative $q$ work (which is quite counter-intuitive). For example, $f(x) =\lfloor x \rfloor+1$.

Comment: @DS, what about $f(x)=\lfloor -x\rfloor+1$? I am most likely just being heedless, but it seems to then work for positive $q$. You probably have already worked this example. I am not in the mood to  check it.

Comment: I don't think $\lfloor -x \rfloor + 1$works

Comment: $q>2$ work too, I think.

Comment: Why vote to delete? For lacking a proof?